# error message in arcanist git: SKIP STAGING Unable to determine repository for this change

Tags: powershell, phabricator, arcanist

I've created a revision in Phabricator using arcanist. In my revision, the files I've edited are empty and only display this message: "The contents of this file were not changed."

In Windows Powershell I've used the right directory: C:\development\dgb, then I used the command arc diff --create. All the files which I edited are included and there are no linting errors. After writing a message and submitting my revision, Powershell displays the following message: "SKIP STAGING  Unable to determine repository for this change."

Does anyone know what the above error message means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. Apparently Arcanist doesn't like file name changes. I made a back-up of the files with the changed names, removed the edited content and committed those files directly. Then I added the content from the back-up files and updated my revision. Everything looks fine now.